# How to rearrange multiple buttons on Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am  developing Calculator.

I took some sample code from here.

My first challenge for me is how to create 9 buttons in a loop without writing anything to the xml file, just in the code.

So I used this piece of code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);  //Can also be done in xml by android:orientation="vertical"

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            LinearLayout row = new LinearLayout(this);
            row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                Button btnTag = new Button(this);
                btnTag.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                btnTag.setText(String.valueOf (j + 1 + (i * 3)));
                btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 3));
                row.addView(btnTag);
            }

            layout.addView(row);
        }
        setContentView(layout);

    }
```

The results showing in the picture.

[Screeshot of the output](https://goo.gl/photos/bmWPzHDEPr3cCtXF9)

The question here is how can I position every button little bit further way from the other .

If I am changing the btnTag.setText that change the text position on the button itself.

I am actually want to change the button position.

I know it something to do with row.setLayoutParams.

1. Anyone familiar with this ?
2. The compiler shouts that FILL_PARENT is deprecated any idea what replaces it. ?

Thanks
Eran

Comment: FILL_PARENT is deprecated so use MATCH_PARENT and why not use the xml file to do the layout?

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer regarding FILL_PARENT, In the beginning I used the XML create each button separately. It become huge xml file. Also I want to make sure if I want to make changes in the future I will make it in one place that is in the code. not in both places i.e code + xml file. Again I beginning with this. From former experience Write code in many files in order to complete one task creates challenges when we need to go back in order to make changes.. If I can avoided that's good if not meaning I can not reposition the buttons I will use the XML file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read more about [addView method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View,%20int,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) 
For your case:
1. For more space between buttons:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
// margin with other button here
params.leftMargin = 10;
params.rightMargin = 10;
btnTag.setLayoutParams(params);
btnTag.setText(String.valueOf (j + 1 + (i * 3)));
btnTag.setId(j + 1 + (i * 3));
```

2. For change button position: Let's say you have lay out like this: 
   row1 : 0 - 1 - 2
   row2 : 3 - 4 - 5
   row3 : 6 - 7 - 8
   And you want to switch position of button 1 and button 5

   `// get the buttons
   View btn1 = row1.getChildAt(1);
   View btn5 = row2.getChildAt(2);
   // remove buttons
   row1.removeView(btn1);
   row2.removeView(btn5);
   // add in new position
   row2.addView(btn1, 2);
   row1.addView(btn5, 1);`

Hope this help.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, in the begining I was trying to add button to the view with view.Addview(button1) but from some reason Addview was not there .... I am using last version....  I went for the simple approch basically I am creating everything in the xml